# Plotting a triangular signal and finding its Fourier transformation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I have the following code for **rectangular** pulse:

```
clear all
dt=.001;
t=[-25:dt:25];
x=(5/2)*(sign(t+10)-sign(t-10));
%subplot(2,2,1);
plot(t,x);
title('Rectangular pulse with width 10ms');
xlabel('time(ms)');
ylabel('Amplitude(V)');
axis([-25 25 0 6]);
>> y=fftshift(fft(x));  % moving the zero-frequency component to the center of the array
N=length(y);         %to take the frquecny axis of the hoarmonics.
n=-(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2;  %divide the frequency compone
f=sqrt(y.*conj(y)); % to take the amplitude of each hoarmony.

title('Rectangular pulse amplitude');
xlabel('frequency component(harmoney)');
ylabel('Amplitude of the harmoney');

plot(n,f);  
axis([-50 50 0 150000]); 
>> 
>> y=fftshift(fft(x));  % moving the zero-frequency component to the center of the array
N=length(y);         %to take the frquecny axis of the hoarmonics.
n=-(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2;  %divide the frequency compone
f=sqrt(y.*conj(y)); % to take the amplitude of each hoarmony.

title('Rectangular pulse amplitude');
xlabel('frequency component(harmoney)');
ylabel('Amplitude of the harmoney');

plot(n,f);  
axis([-50 50 0 150000]);
```

How to get a triangular pulse?

Also, the above code doesn't find the Fourier transformation of a rectangular signal. How to find it? How to find it for triangular signal? Is it possible to compute it in MATLAB or to evaluate it manually?

Comment: Change `x=(5/2)*(sign(t+10)-sign(t-10));` to `x=max(5-abs(t),0);`

Comment: You can do FT manually, you can google some lecture notes on that. MATLAB can do it as well: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fourier.html

Answer (score 0):

The length of time signal should be sufficiently long, to get proper resolution on frequency domain.

Please, try to change your time period like this.

```
t=[-100:dt:100];
```

In terms of triangular signal, I think, the comment of brainkz is the best.

In your case, please change your time signal like this.

```
x=0.5*max(10-abs(t),0);
```